# There is an array with some numbers. All numbers are equal except for one. How i can found only that number in python?

Tags: python

There is an array with some numbers. All numbers are equal except for one. How i can found only that number in python?

uniq([ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ]) == 2

I use 'set' but it print me [1, 2]...

Comment: What if the list is `[7, 8]`? :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way to implement your problem:

> ```
> def count_unique(s,lst):
>     for i in lst:
>         if(lst.count(i)==1):
>             return i
> lst=list(map(int,input().split()))
> s=list(set(lst))
> print(count_unique(s,lst))
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the list to a set to get all of items in the list and then by using `count` function find out which one of them only exists in the list only once.

```
for i in set(arr):
    if arr.count(i) == 1:
        print(i)
```

or list comprehension:

```
[i for i in set(arr) if arr.count(i) == 1]
```

this way you can get all the items in list that occur once.
[this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-element-that-appears-once/) might also help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

    def find_unique(list1):
    count = Counter(list1)

    if len(list1) >= 3:
        for key, value in count.items():
            if value == 1:
                return key
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use `collections.Counter` for this as follows:

```
import collections
x = [ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ]
occurs = collections.Counter(x)
for k, v in occurs.items():
    if v == 1:
        print(k)
```

output:

```
2
```

Explanation: `occurs` is dict with pairs of value - how many times it appears, I print all values which appeared exactly once.